# jQuery toggle class function issue

Tags: jquery

How can I achieve this with jQuery?

- If `<a href="#" class="accordion-link">` is clicked, add class 'active'.
- If any other `<a href="#" class="accordion-link">` is clicked, hide active from all and add to this.
- If `<a href="#" class="accordion-link active">` is clicked, remove "active" (this last one is in the event they close the div that is currently active, it will remove the 'active' class).

Comment: Use backticks (`) to mark inline code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('.accordion-link').click(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.hasClass('active')) {
        t.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        t.siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
        t.addClass('active');
    }

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QA7mU/

Answer (score 1):

That should do what you want:

$(".accordion-link").on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var wasActive = $this.is('.active');

```
$(".accordion-link").removeClass("active");
if (!wasActive) {
    $this.addClass("active");
}
```

});

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyk3n/)